# Apache2, FastCGI, PHP5 and urls without .php sufix

Tags: php, joomla1.5, apache2.4, mod-fastcgi

I have to configure my Apache2 server to host an old web application, based on Joomla 1.5. 
Apache is running on Debian Stretch, with PHP 7 as mod_php. I manage to install PHP 5.6 as FastCgi module and it looks like working as an alternative to PHP 7.

My VirtualHost looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName site.pl

  DocumentRoot /var/www/site/html
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

  <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
  </FilesMatch>

</Virtualhost>
```

And it works very well with basic urls, like:

```
http://site.pl/index.php
```

The problem is with other urls generated by this old CMS, like:

```
http://site.pl/index.php/category/page
```

I get 404 error, obviously.

I don't know how to keep this kind of urls and handle them with FastCgi proxy.
What FileMatch cover this url?
Any ideas?

Comment: When you have Joomla-specific questions, please post them at Joomla Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

The argument in `FilesMatch` appears to be a regular expression, so you could adapt it to also match URLs generated by the old CMS, for example:

```
.+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml)(/.*)*$
```

Notice the `(/.*)*` at the end, which matches the additional path after `index.php`, but can be omitted, so that URLs without path are also matched.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I don't know really why but with such a configuration FileMatch doesn't cover even basic urls (like http://site.pl/index.php).

Comment: Can you try again, with the added `*` at the end?